# Postgresql: query DATE column using unix timestamp?

Tags: postgresql

I am running the following query:

```
select *
from car c
where c.updated_at >= to_timestamp(1660346076)::date
```

1660346076 = Fri Aug 12 2022 23:14:36 GMT+0000

One of the records I get back is before that date. In Datagrip the car row that should not show up from that query has the following `update_at`:

```
2022-08-12 22:59:07.625179 +00:00
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `select to_timestamp(1660346076)::date; 2022-08-12` and since you are comparing to `timestamp` it becomes `select to_timestamp(1660346076)::date::timestamp; 2022-08-12 00:00:00` which makes `2022-08-12 22:59:07.625179 +00:00 >= 2022-08-12 00:00:00`.

Comment: removing the cast to date fixes the problem. Thanks. If you post it as an answer I can mark it resolved.

Comment: Why not just use `>= timestamp '2022-08-13 00:14:36'`?

Comment: In the actual codebase the timestamp value is passed in as a variable via an endpoint...